# Regular expression for none or one slash in a string

Tags: php, regex, slash

I have some URLs like:

```
dir-1
dir-1/dir-2
dir-1/dir-2/dir-3
dir-1/dir-2/dir-3/dir-[n]..and so on..
```

My current regex (with PHP) looks like this:

```
/^([[:lower:][:digit:]\-\/]+)$/
```

So the regex matches all URLs. But in my case, I need only the first and second version, so that there is NONE or only one occurrence of a slash.

I tried multiple times to figure out the right way, but with no result.

Comment: A little more information as to why you need to specifically use regex would be helpful. Thus far I'm thinking the explode answer is the best unless there is a specific reason you -must- use regex.

Comment: I currently have about 20.000 URLs (and in the future many, many more) which have combinations of the first and second version, followed by static directory levels. Exmaples: /lastname-1/dates/ /lastname-2/dates/ /lastname-1/firstname-1/dates/ and so on.. I try to figure out the right to handle this, but I am still in development :) But the first answer from Amber is currently the right.

Comment: Are you mining this from a static text source, or is it something that you generate? If it's something that you generate in php, I still like the explode answer below of @Lix. I'm just trying to get an idea of why you specifically need regex (since in most cases it can (and should) be avoided).

Comment: The URLs were generated by data stored in a database. The database grows as the content grows. The URLs were in some way static and in some way dynamic. I think I will try the explode-method, combined with switches and if-conditions to avoid regex. Fortunately I am in the position to try another method before it goes in production :)

Comment: Marv - If you decided to use my solution in the end you might want to consider changing your accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match that set of characters (minus a `/`), then an optional `/`, then that set of characters again (optionally).

```
/^([[:lower:][:digit:]-]+\/?[[:lower:][:digit:]-]*)$/
```

Comment: O, I C... Deleted previous comment, and +1.

Answer (score 2):

You could just explode the string using the slash as the delimiter -

```php
$str = "dir-1/dir-2";    
$splitArr = explode('/',$str);
```

- If the resulting array has more than one element then a slash is present.
- More than two elements == more than one slash!

```
array (
  0 => 'dir-1',
  1 => 'dir-2',
)
```

As your question states you are not talking about [any old string](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v692/Rodsbucket/Other%20Long%20Bows/CNV00014.jpg) variable buy specifically URL's, make sure to remove the `http` or `https` protocol from the beginning of the string :

Eg:  `https://marvin.com/dir-1/dir-2`

You could possibly use the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` variable - this returns the current URL relative to the sites `DOCUMENT ROOT`.

So the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` of `https://marvin.com/dir-1/dir-2` would be :

`/dir-1/dir-2` <sub>(look familiar?)</sub>

After the `explode()` you could also use `array_shift()` to remove the initial *root* slash and
**HEY PRESTO!** you have avoided using regular expressions!

[<sub>Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)